# Transctional readOnly=true & saving objects in Grails and Postgres

Tags: hibernate, spring, postgresql, grails

We are using Grails [Spring+Hibernate] and have one service method with @Transactional(readOnly=true). During development & tests we were using HSQLDB and the behaviour was such that we could use .save(flush:true) and object would be saved to the database, but all other objects would be rolled back.
Everything was great accept for when we switched to Postgres. Now this settings throws back:
ERROR - transaction is read only.

EDIT:

We have to be able to rollback all the data in the transaction but still be able to save the data we require to be saved [some additional stuff, not related to the transaction, like something for logging purposes]. It don't want to use any DB triggers to do that. We also don't want to get Stale Object Exceptions when saving stuff after the original request was served.
Any ideas on how we could achieve that? The only thing that comes to my mind is to have some kind a registry where we would store references to modified objects and at the end drop all changes, but this is the last resort. I am sure there's a way to tackle this issue without doing stupid things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so we've found the solution.
It's in grails jira:

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8513?focusedCommentId=68436&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-68436

Answer (score 2):

I think spring just calls connection.setReadOnly(true) and then it's up to the jdbc driver. Maybe HSQLDB jdbc takes that only as a hint to optimize something. [Posgresql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-set-transaction.html) are clear on the read-only semantics:

> When a transaction is read-only, the following SQL commands are disallowed: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and COPY FROM if the table they would write to is not a temporary table; all CREATE, ALTER, and DROP commands; COMMENT, GRANT, REVOKE, TRUNCATE; and EXPLAIN ANALYZE and EXECUTE if the command they would execute is among those listed.

Comment: Thanks Milan. However this is not a Postrgres DB transaction which is set to readonly but Spring transaction.Save should create a new transaction only to save the stuff and commit it straight away. Everything else has auto rollback so nothing is saved to the database. I think you just thought about this transaction as DB transaction rather than Spring transaction.

Comment: well then spring obviously doesn't open a new RW transaction for save

Comment: what happens if you explicitly specify REQUIRES_NEW for save?

Answer (score 0):

milan. I work with Krystian and on this particular problem. I`ve tested all the propagation  fields to solve it and none of them worked (PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, REQUIRES_NEW and NESTED looked worth trying).

Comment: with REQUIRES_NEW, you're sure that the new transaction is not-read only again? can you debug, go into jdbc if necessary?  i doubt it's a spring bug (someone would've hit it before), so there has to be something you're not doing properly. why dont you strip down the code, or even better, start a new mini project that just exposes this 'bug'. when i try this, i usually discover bugs in my code or setup. and if it stil doesn't work, you can put it online and ask someone to have a look.